# Use of a variable in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called lprPostcodeRegion with Region Name and Region ID. I would like to calculate the following sum based on the region ID. For instance, for region ID 1 I would get a certain sum, for region ID 2 I would get a different sum and this happens for approximately 15 IDs.

As you can see I have declared the RegionID as 1 therefore, I only get the sum for RegionID1 (lpr.regionID = 1/ lpr.regionID = @RegionID). How can I automatically calculate the sum for all of the Region IDs?

```
DECLARE @RegionID int; 
SET @RegionID = 1;
SELECT lpr.RegionID,
    --wc.whsHeaderID,
SUM(c.[Chargeable Weight]) AS LeftOffWt
FROM    dbo.whsConsignment wc
    INNER JOIN whsHeader wh on wh.WhsHeaderID = wc.whsHeaderID
    INNER JOIN dbo.cgtConsignment c ON c.[Consignment Reference] = wc.ConsignmentReference
    INNER JOIN dbo.genAddress ga ON ga.AddressID = c.Consignor
    INNER JOIN dbo.lstPostcode lp ON lp.Postcode = ga.PostcodePrefix
    INNER JOIN dbo.lstPostcodeRegion lpr ON lpr.RegionID = lp.RegionID
              AND c.Cancelled = 0
              --AND wc.ConsignmentReference LIKE '4%'
              and lpr.RegionID = 1
WHERE   StatusCode IN ( 'NL' ) and wh.ArrDepDate between @StartDate and @EndDate
GROUP BY lpr.RegionID
```

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to match the post title. Are you looking for a procedure that will accept a variable and calculate the sum for that record? Or are you looking for a query that will always return the sum for all regions?

Comment: Isn't that what your query is doing? (If you remove `and lpr.RegionID = 1` condition)

Comment: since you are using group by,i dont see any issue in removing this in your code ` and lpr.RegionID = 1`,so that it will get sum for all regionids

Comment: Remove and lpr.RegionID = 1... and you aren't using that variable so the declaration is pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

– Sean Lange is right, you cant juse more then one value.. my mistake 
Go on Deans ide

```
   SELECT lpr.RegionID,
                        --wc.whsHeaderID,
                        SUM(c.[Chargeable Weight]) AS LeftOffWt
                FROM    dbo.whsConsignment wc
                        INNER JOIN whsHeader wh on wh.WhsHeaderID = wc.whsHeaderID
                        INNER JOIN dbo.cgtConsignment c ON c.[Consignment Reference] = wc.ConsignmentReference
                        INNER JOIN dbo.genAddress ga ON ga.AddressID = c.Consignor
                        INNER JOIN dbo.lstPostcode lp ON lp.Postcode = ga.PostcodePrefix
                        INNER JOIN dbo.lstPostcodeRegion lpr ON lpr.RegionID = lp.RegionID
                                                          AND c.Cancelled = 0
                                                          --AND wc.ConsignmentReference LIKE '4%'

                WHERE   StatusCode IN ( 'NL' ) and wh.ArrDepDate between @StartDate and @EndDate 
                GROUP BY lpr.RegionID
```

Comment: You can't use a variable like that at all. This just isn't even close to a viable answer.

Comment: Diana don't do this. The value for @RegionID is a scalar variable, it cannot hold multiple values like this post suggests. If you want more than 1 region this is not going to work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the lpr.RegionID = 1. Here is a sample:

```
 SELECT lpr.RegionID,
                        --wc.whsHeaderID,
                        SUM(c.[Chargeable Weight]) AS LeftOffWt
                FROM    dbo.whsConsignment wc
                        INNER JOIN whsHeader wh on wh.WhsHeaderID = wc.whsHeaderID
                        INNER JOIN dbo.cgtConsignment c ON c.[Consignment Reference] = wc.ConsignmentReference
                        INNER JOIN dbo.genAddress ga ON ga.AddressID = c.Consignor
                        INNER JOIN dbo.lstPostcode lp ON lp.Postcode = ga.PostcodePrefix
                        INNER JOIN dbo.lstPostcodeRegion lpr ON lpr.RegionID = lp.RegionID
                                                          AND c.Cancelled = 0
                                                          --AND wc.ConsignmentReference LIKE '4%'
                WHERE   StatusCode IN ( 'NL' ) and wh.ArrDepDate between @StartDate and @EndDate
                GROUP BY lpr.RegionID
```